# Matching lower bound on maximum of 2-norm of sub-vectors of standard Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $Y$ be a $d$-dimensional standard Gaussian vector, i.e. $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_d)$. For any subset $S\subset[d]=\{1,2,\cdots,d\}$, let $|S|$ be the size of $S$ and $Y_S$ be the subvector $(Y_i:i\in S)$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547487/gaussian-width-of-sparse-balls) shows the following: there is some universal constant $c>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\max_{|S|=k}||Y_S||_2\leq c\sqrt{k\log\frac{ed}{k}},$$

I would also like to know whether this bound is tight (eg. whether there is some other constant $c'>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}\max_{|S|=k}||Y_S||_2\geq c'\sqrt{k\log\frac{ed}{k}}$). My main concern is, the upper bound proof therein seems to be ignorance of the dependence structure between $Y_S$ and $Y_{S'}$, while this might be a problem for the lower bound?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.gautamkamath.com/writings/gaussian_max.pdf) help?

Comment: @sudeep5221: maybe I missed some point, but I think independence is needed in their proof.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood your question. Yeah, the independence is needed in their question but it is not true here.

Comment: I think you can still use that argument in the linked article. Use the fact that expectation of max is more than the expectation of an average vector chosen uniformly at random with $|S| = k$.